# Why do my WD blue 4tb disks show up as 2tb in gparted, gdisk, parted, and fdisk

Tags: lubuntu, gparted, gpt

They're attached using a dual sas raid card. The goal is to use mdadm to create a large raid 6 array for nas purposes and a plex server. But I'm not going to try to create a massive 24tb array if I can't even seem to format 4tb.

```
nasplex@nasplex-pc:~$ sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.4

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.

Command (? for help): ^C
nasplex@nasplex-pc:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdc
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sdc
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print                                                            
Model: ATA WDC WD40EZRZ-19G (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2199GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name              Flags
 1      1049kB  2199GB  2199GB               Linux filesystem

(parted) ^C                                                               

nasplex@nasplex-pc:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.102 TiB, 2199023254528 bytes, 4294967294 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EZRZ-19G
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B128F58D-0CAC-4EF4-B57A-B0883ACD65EC

Device     Start        End    Sectors Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 4294967260 4294965213   2T Linux filesystem
nasplex@nasplex-pc:~$ 

nasplex@nasplex-pc:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 111.8G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   5.6G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0 460.2G  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0     2T  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0     2T  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0     2T  0 disk 
sde      8:64   0     2T  0 disk 
sdf      8:80   0     2T  0 disk 
sdg      8:96   0     2T  0 disk 
sdh      8:112  0     2T  0 disk 
sdi      8:128  0     2T  0 disk 
sdj      8:144  0     2T  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: What OS/release?  (you tagged lubuntu but gave no further details)

Comment: Why mdadm with a sas raid card? What is your raid card? Can it handle  drives larger than 2Gb? Could/Should its firmware be updated?...

Comment: This seems unusual: `Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B` Most new large drives are 512/4K. https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-4kb-sector-disks/  Post this: `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sdc, you canceled the details. You need the -l or use a command to show details: http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/walkthrough.html & 
http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/

Comment: Basically clean installation of the latest desktop version of lubuntu x86_64 download a couple days ago. Mdadm because my raid card is an ancient ebay special and can only do 1 or 2 won't do raid 6. I'm going to look for a firmware update tonight. Maybe that'll work, and maybe even do raid 6 natively. I'll post full output of gdisk tonight too. I'll also try to figure out exactly what the card is and post that too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I was using an old raid card. An lsi sas 3801E which only supports up to 2tb disks. See this: Broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161495837/using-drives-2tb-in-capacity-with-lsi-sas-hbas

Thanks to reddit, and everyone here